# MySql: Returning MAX Value in joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max

I've got 3 tables joined here. There's the Customers, Orders, and Items ordered by Customers. These are named: CustomersTbl, OrdersTbl, OrderedItemTbl.

I'm arranging all the Orders made with their total price, and displaying the customer who made the order's name.

```
select * from productstbl;
select * from ordereditemtbl;
select * from orderstbl;

select 
    ordereditemtbl.ItemID,
    customerstbl.CustomerID,
    customerstbl.FirstName,
    orderstbl.OrderID,
    orderstbl.OrderDate,
    sum(ordereditemtbl.amount * productstbl.Price) as totalPrice
from
    ordereditemtbl
        inner join
    ProductsTbl ON ordereditemtbl.productID = productstbl.productID
        inner join
    orderstbl ON ordereditemtbl.orderID = ordereditemtbl.orderID
        inner join
    customerstbl ON customerstbl.customerID = orderstbl.customerID#'2'
group by ordereditemTbl.OrderID
order by totalPrice desc;
```

Now I'd like to display the Order with the highest TotalPrice alone. How can I get the max value of it? Is there a way to possibly use the MAX() function?

Comment: `order by  MAX(totalPrice)`

Comment: Nope. Sadly I'm getting the following: 'Error 1247: Reference totalPrice not supported'. I tried fixing it by putting totalPrice's value: sum(ordereditemtbl.amount * productstbl.Price). Got me to Error 1111: 'Invalid use of group function'.

Comment: `... order by totalPrice desc LIMIT 1` See the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html). Also note that you have an error in line `orderstbl ON ordereditemtbl.orderID = ordereditemtbl.orderID`, I guess you meant `orderstbl ON ordereditemtbl.orderID = erderstbl.orderID`

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. Check out if this works:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
select 
    ordereditemtbl.ItemID,
    customerstbl.CustomerID,
    customerstbl.FirstName,
    orderstbl.OrderID,
    orderstbl.OrderDate,
    sum(ordereditemtbl.amount * productstbl.Price) as totalPrice,
    @rownum AS row_number
from
    ordereditemtbl
        inner join
    ProductsTbl ON ordereditemtbl.productID = productstbl.productID
        inner join
    orderstbl ON ordereditemtbl.orderID = ordereditemtbl.orderID
        inner join
    customerstbl ON customerstbl.customerID = orderstbl.customerID#'2'
        inner join
    (SELECT @rownum := 0) dummy
group by ordereditemTbl.OrderID
ORDER BY totalPrice desc;
)
WHERE row_number=0
```

This allots a row number and picks the top row.

Cheers,
Ram

Comment: Well we're missing the alias for each table, but after I added that I got 0 rows returned.

Comment: I don't understand, I copied _your_ query, am I supposed to have added aliases?

Comment: I'm really a beginner in SQL, I'm only learning these stuff through mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by abl, I have added the following at the end of the code:

```
order by totalPrice desc LIMIT 1;
```

Shows the first row of the table created, as it's shown in descending values.
Thanks!